# How to detect location more intelligently in Nginx config file?

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting, localization, internationalization, globalization

I'm trying to use `location` to detect the current locale and transfer (rewrite) the request in my Nginx config file.

This is a my configuration:

```
location /ru 
{
    rewrite ^/ru/(.*)$ /$1?local=ru;
    rewrite ^/ru /?local=ru;
}
```

So, I intend to change `domain.tld/ru/blog` to `domain.tld/blog?locale=ru`.

But I have encountered one problem. As an example, the URL `domain.tld/russell` would interfere with this config blog.

I want to be able to get more specific for `location` syntax. I want to tell Nginx to run this block only and if only the URL starts with a two-letter `ru` path segment.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

To match `/ru` and `/ru/foo` but not `/rufoo`, you could use a [regular expression location](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location). But note that the evaluation order of regular expression locations is significant.

```
location ~* /ru($|/) { ... }
```

---

Alternatively, use two location blocks:

```
location = /ru { rewrite ^ /?local=ru; }
location /ru/ { rewrite ^/ru/(.*)$ /$1?local=ru; }
```

Comment: Thank you so much. So, the `/ru` location won't match `/rufoo`? Because we already have that one location and it matched `/rufoo` too.

Comment: `location /ru` matches anything that begins with `/ru` unless a more specific location matches instead. `location = /ru` matches only `/ru` and nothing else.

Comment: Then how that would solve our problem? I mean how having two separate location blocks saves us from that problem?

Comment: Because neither of those two locations match `/russell`

Comment: Oh, now I saw the `=` sign. That makes it more specific. That is so nice. Thank you so much.